# How to Split a String to show in different columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have a table name `rankList` with columns `instituteCode` and `rank`

Table `rankList` data

```
----------------------------------------------------
instituteCode       |  rank                     
----------------------------------------------------
1125                |  1,3,7
1259                |  11,16,19,28
1902                |  2,4,5,6,8,9,10
----------------------------------------------------
```

so as per the example table we can see all the `rank` are stored in single column, so i need a desired output to show the selected `instituteCode` ranks must split in different column

so i already tried this using regular expression for the `instituteCode` `1125`

```
select 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(rank,',',1) as  firstColumn,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(rank,',',2),',',-1) as secondColumn,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(rank,',',-1) as  thirdColumn
from ranklist where instituteCode='1125'
```

Output is

```
------------------------------------------
firstColumn | secondColumn | thirdColumn
------------------------------------------
1           | 3            |7
------------------------------------------
```

but the problem is, to get the output for `1259` and `1902` i must rewrite the entire query. is there any other way to split according to the `rank` and 
store in multiple columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: rank are unique for individual instituteCode, wont it help ?

Comment: You need to fix the original data (and how do you store it). Normalize it. Otherwise, you will get into requirements for such complex queries later, which will be extremely inefficient.

Comment: Let's say you have 100 comma separated values in a column. Now, you can imagine how many substring_index you would write.